# beautifulsoup find_all title

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, request, web-crawler

html is

```
<div class="trn-defstat__value">
    <img src="https://trackercdn.com/rainbow6-ubi/assets/images/badge-ash.16913d82e3.png" title="ASH" style="height:    35px; padding-right: 8px;"> 
    <img src="https://trackercdn.com/rainbow6-ubi/assets/images/badge-jager.600b2773be.png" title="JÄGER"   style="height: 35px; padding-right: 8px;">
    <img src="https://trackercdn.com/rainbow6-ubi/assets/images/badge-bandit.385144d970.png" title="BANDIT"     style="height: 35px; padding-right: 8px;">
</div>
```

I want to get each title value.

But before that, I write like this

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests


bsURL = "https://r6.tracker.network/profile/pc/Spoit.GODSENT"
respinse = requests.get(bsURL)
html = bs(respinse.text, 'html.parser')


title = html.find_all(class_='trn-defstat__value')[4]

print(title)
```

Result ->

```
<div class="trn-defstat__value">
<img src="https://trackercdn.com/rainbow6-ubi/assets/images/badge-ash.16913d82e3.png" style="height: 35px; padding-right: 8px;" title="ASH"/>
<img src="https://trackercdn.com/rainbow6-ubi/assets/images/badge-jager.600b2773be.png" style="height: 35px; padding-right: 8px;" title="JÄGER"/>
<img src="https://trackercdn.com/rainbow6-ubi/assets/images/badge-bandit.385144d970.png" style="height: 35px; padding-right: 8px;" title="BANDIT"/>
</div>
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

This script will print all `<img>` titles from Top Operators section:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests


bsURL = "https://r6.tracker.network/profile/pc/Spoit.GODSENT"
respinse = requests.get(bsURL)
html = bs(respinse.text, 'html.parser')

# find Top Operators tag
operators = html.find(class_='trn-defstat__name', text='Top Operators')

for img in operators.find_next('div').find_all('img'):
    print(img['title'])
```

Prints:

```
ASH
JÄGER
BANDIT
```

---

Or using CSS:

```
for img in html.select('.trn-defstat__name:contains("Top Operators") + * img'):
    print(img['title'])
```

Comment: thanks you  I'll take this into consideration, too.

Answer (score 0):

This should help u:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div class="trn-defstat__value">
    <img src="https://trackercdn.com/rainbow6-ubi/assets/images/badge-ash.16913d82e3.png" title="ASH" style="height:    35px; padding-right: 8px;"> 
    <img src="https://trackercdn.com/rainbow6-ubi/assets/images/badge-jager.600b2773be.png" title="JÄGER"   style="height: 35px; padding-right: 8px;">
    <img src="https://trackercdn.com/rainbow6-ubi/assets/images/badge-bandit.385144d970.png" title="BANDIT"     style="height: 35px; padding-right: 8px;">
</div>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

imgs = soup.find_all('img')

for img in imgs:
    print(img['title'])
```

Output:

```
ASH
JÄGER
BANDIT
```

Here is the complete code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

bsURL = "https://r6.tracker.network/profile/pc/Spoit.GODSENT"
respinse = requests.get(bsURL)
html = bs(respinse.text, 'html.parser')
divs = html.find_all('div',class_ = "trn-defstat__value")
imgs = []
for div in divs:
    try:
        imgs.append(div.find_all('img'))
    except:
        pass

imgs = [ele for ele in imgs if ele != []]
imgs = [j for sub in imgs for j in sub]

for img in imgs:
    print(img['title'])
```

Output:

```
ASH
JÄGER
BANDIT
```

Comment: i changed my code like this 
```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests


bsURL = "https://r6.tracker.network/profile/pc/Spoit.GODSENT"
respinse = requests.get(bsURL)
html = bs(respinse.text, 'html.parser')



imgs = html.find_all(".trn-defstat__value")['img']

for img in imgs:
    print(img.get("title"))
``` but its an error
What should I do?

Comment: @레이화이트raywhite Check my updated code. It works perfectly fine without any errors

Comment: If u find my answer helpful, pls accept it as the best answer. Also, u forgot to accept another answer that I gave (to the previous ques that u asked) as the best answer. Make sure that u accept even that answer as the best answer. And also make sure that u upvote both of my answers. Thank you!

Comment: what is mean`index = 0
imgs = [ele for ele in imgs if ele != []]
imgs = [j for sub in imgs for j in sub]`

Comment: tbh you don't need to find all `div`s with classes of `trn-defstat__value` and try all of them cause there are other div tags with the same class and different content so you would just be going through nothing. The data you want to find I believe is at the class `trn-defstat mb0 top-operators` and `div` is its tag and luckily it is unique or the only the so you won't have any problems with other tags with the same class. But anyways, your question.. your answer :)

Comment: @IceBear I agree with u. But I think that the OP was tryna get all the div tags and then loop thru those div tags to get the image titles

Comment: @레이화이트raywhite ```imgs = [ele for ele in imgs if ele != []]``` just removes the empty values in the list and ```imgs = [j for sub in imgs for j in sub]``` just flattens the list (converts the list from 2d to 1d). Hope that this answers ur question.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `.get()` function to get the attribute and pass in the attribute name.

```
pip install html5lib
```

I suggest you use that, I believe it's a better parser.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs 
import requests   
bsURL = "https://r6.tracker.network/profile/pc/Spoit.GODSENT" 

respinse = requests.get(bsURL) 



html = bs(respinse.content, 'html5lib')   


container = html.find("div", class_= "trn-defstat mb0 top-operators")


imgs = container.find_all("img")


for img in imgs:
     print(img.get("title"))
```

I did not seem to understand what part of the site you were trying to scrape but take note of it to sometimes get first the `block` of html code where there are the details you want to scraped :)

Comment: `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests


bsURL = "https://r6.tracker.network/profile/pc/Spoit.GODSENT"
respinse = requests.get(bsURL)
html = bs(respinse.text, 'html5lib')


imgs = html.find_all("img", class_= "trn-defstat__value")

for img in imgs:
    print(img.get("title"))` i write like this but resualt is null

Comment: try `response.content` instead of `response.text`

Comment: probably the value of class is wrong or you should get first the `content` tag that has the `imgs` tags you want to scrape

Comment: that resault is null... same

Comment: I've inspected the website you are trying to scrape there are a lot of tags that has the class `trn-defstat__value` so it would not be good to directly `.find()` in the `soup` variable. I suggest you find first the block of html code that contains those `img` tags

Comment: how can i find specify block?

Comment: If u find my answer helpful, pls accept it as the best answer. Also, u forgot to accept another answer that I gave u (the previous ques that u asked) as the best answer. Make sure that u accept even that answer as the best answer. And also make sure that u upvote both of my answers. Thank you!

Comment: @Sushil i have a more question.I want to put each result in a variable. How do i do this?

Comment: since you have a number of results. I think it's best you put it in a `list`. You can simply just create a `list` and `.append()` it

Comment: S. As @IceBear said, just append all the values to a list.

Comment: I mean since you have multiple results you can put it in a list :)